# Regex to replace timezone offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string representing date/time with timezone. I want to change the timezone part to UTC that is `+00:00`

Please help me to write regext to match `+05:30`, `-03:30` etc and replace it with `+00:00`

I tried with  `"2012-04-17T15:40+05:30".gsub!(/\+\d\d:\d\d/, '+00:00')` which gives me expected results but I don't know how to match `-5:30`

I would appreciate if someone helps me to write regex which work with both `2012-04-17T15:40+05:30` and `2012-04-17T15:40-05:30`

Thanks,
Amit Patel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"2012-04-17T15:40+05:30".gsub!(/[+-]\d\d:\d\d/, '+00:00')
```

will replace both positive and negative offsets. But why?

Comment: My application receives date/time in user's timezone. At some points in the application I want to consider the time as if it is in UTC. So before giving `params[:date]` I replace it's TZ part in `before_filter` so rest is taken care by AR

Answer (score 1):

How about simple:

```
str = "2012-04-17T15:40+05:30"
str.sub!(/.{6}\z/, '+00:00') # => "2012-04-17T15:40+00:00"
```

Comment: It also worked but above two looks more cleaner. Thanks for sharing, @jdoe.

Comment: `/.{6}\z/` -- is something may be cleaner? :)

Comment: I just payed attention in mu answer to your exclamation mark `!` at the end of the sub/gsub. With this mark the function replaces the content of the string it applied to. So it's more logical to use it not for literal but for variable. I guess you got the idea.

Comment: I have used literal so it is more readable here but I have variable which is being manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to

```
/(\+|\-)\d\d:\d\d/
```

Comment: But I'm also curious about what you are trying to accomplish.  It looks to me that you are discarding the time zone information about the local time.

Comment: Yes, I just commented in below answer.